# How to list all possible combination of words

Tags: string, excel, combinations, permutation, formula

I have four words and need to list all possible combinations of the words.(duplicates are not required):

```
 CAT
 DOG
 MOUSE
 FROG
 BIRD
```

so possible combinationss could be:

- **1.** CAT, DOG, MOUSE, FROG, BIRD
- **2.** CAT, DOG
- **3.** CAT,
- **4.** MOUSE, DOG

etc.

I do not want duplicates so `CAT, DOG` = `DOG, CAT`.

How do I write a formula in Excel to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried anything? In excel if you open up developer tools you can write a program using VBA

Comment: To help you with the terminology, this is  a question of combinations and permutations... specifically combinations (not permutations). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: To be honest I wouldn't know where to start with VBA as i have very little dev experience. Is there a built in function that can help achieve this in Excel?

Comment: Think about this logically and then try to transform it into code - how would a human do it? ie - start with `CAT` and loop through all of the words and print out combinations.

Comment: This is great problem for [`R`](https://www.r-project.org/) -- `animals <- c('cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'frog', 'bird'); lapply(1:length(animals), function(i) combn(animals, i))` will give you the answer. You can even use [r-fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/) to avoid installing `R` locally. Here's a [link to the fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=AQQDJQT4).

Comment: There is no formula to help with this. You could write a series of formulas using `indirect` `row()` `column`, possibly `mod()` that you would tinker with to get all the iterations, but it would be not fun. VBA is probably your best hope.